# Get first form error in django views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm having a problem getting the first error of the form in Django View. Here is what I did:

**views.py**

```
frm = PasswordChangeForm(request.user,request.POST)
    if frm.is_valid():
        frm.save()
    else:           
        jsonStringErrors = frm.errors.as_json()
        jsonErrors = loads(jsonStringErrors)
        old_passwordError = jsonErrors['old_password']                
        if old_passwordError:
            context["error"] = old_passwordError[0]["message"]
        else:
            new_passwordError = jsonErrors["new_password2"]
            if new_passwordError:
                context["error"] = new_passwordError[0]["message"] 
            else:
                context["error"] = frm.errors.as_text()
```

And when the user enters the password correctly I get error on line 7, so I tried

```
old_passwordError = jsonErrors.items()[0]
```

also this

```
old_passwordError = jsonErrors.keys()[0]
```

but I got this error

> 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comments are welcomed, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `list(jsonErrors.keys())[0]` instead of `jsonErrors.keys()[0]`.

The `keys()` method returns a `dict_keys` object, which doesn't support indexing. So converting it to list will allow you to access elements by a specific index.